# Crear un conteo de ingresos al menú

Tags: java

buenas tardes

Estoy elaborando un menú de opciones en Java y necesito realizar un conteo de las veces que se selecciona cada una de las opciones del menú; el menú tendrá lo siguiente:

```
1) Ejercicio #1
2) Ejercicio #2
3) Ejercicio #3
4) Salir
```

Al ingresar por ejemplo a la opción 1, el programa debería de realizar un conteo, para que cuando se seleccione la opción 4 o salir, imprima las estadísticas de cuantas veces se seleccionó cada opción, por ejemplo:

```
Opción 1 = 2 veces
Opción 2 = 0 veces
Opción 3 = 4 veces
```

El código del menú es el siguiente, solo me falta agregarle el contador de ingresos, cualquier ayuda es agradecida

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class menuOpciones {
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); 

        char answer = 's';
        while (answer == 's' || answer == 'S') {

            System.out.println();
            System.out.print("1) Ejercicio #1\n");
            System.out.print("2) Ejercicio #2\n");
            System.out.print("3) Ejercicio #3\n");
            System.out.print("4) Salir\n\n");
            System.out.print("Ingrese la opción deseada: ");

            int menuOption = sc.nextInt();
            
            if (menuOption == 1) { 
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("*** Ejercicio #1 ***");
                System.out.println("--------------------");
                
                //Código ejercicio #1    

            } else if (menuOption == 2) {
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("*** Ejercicio #2 ***");
                System.out.println("--------------------");
                
                //Código ejercicio #2    

            } else if (menuOption == 3) {
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("*** Ejercicio #3 ***");
                System.out.println("--------------------");

                //Código ejercicio #3    
                
            }else if (menuOption == 4) {
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("Gracias por utilizar mi herramienta, hasta pronto!");
                break;

            } else {
                System.out.println("La opción introducida no es valida."); 
            }
            System.out.println();
            System.out.print("Desea continuar? [s/n]: ");
            answer = sc.next().charAt(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Puedes crear una variable dentro de cada uno de los if-else if que sea un contador propio. De esa forma, te guardará en cada variable el número de veces que entró en cada if (que es lo que realmente te interesa), y al final muestra las variables por pantalla. Si necesitas más información dímelo y te hago un ejemplo.

Comment: Gracias amigo por tu pronta respuesta, esto solucionó mi problema.

Comment: Me alegro compañero, espero que tengas un buen día!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Necesitas una variable por cada ejercicio que aumente cada que se seleccione su respectiva opcion

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MenuOpciones {
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int cont1=0;
        int cont2=0;
        int cont3=0;


        char answer = 's';
        while (answer == 's' || answer == 'S') {

            System.out.println();
            System.out.print("1) Ejercicio #1\n");
            System.out.print("2) Ejercicio #2\n");
            System.out.print("3) Ejercicio #3\n");
            System.out.print("4) Salir\n\n");
            System.out.print("Ingrese la opción deseada: ");

            int menuOption = sc.nextInt();
            
            if (menuOption == 1) { 
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("*** Ejercicio #1 ***");
                System.out.println("--------------------");
                cont1++;
                //Código ejercicio #1    

            } else if (menuOption == 2) {
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("*** Ejercicio #2 ***");
                System.out.println("--------------------");
                cont2++;
                //Código ejercicio #2    

            } else if (menuOption == 3) {
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("*** Ejercicio #3 ***");
                System.out.println("--------------------");
                cont3++;
                //Código ejercicio #3    
                
            }else if (menuOption == 4) {
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("Gracias por utilizar mi herramienta, hasta pronto!");
                break;

            } else {
                System.out.println("La opción introducida no es valida."); 
            }
            System.out.println();
            System.out.print("Desea continuar? [s/n]: ");
            answer = sc.next().charAt(0);
        }

           System.out.println("Opcion 1: "+cont1+ " veces");
           System.out.println("Opcion 2: "+cont2+ " veces" );
           System.out.println("Opcion 3: "+cont3+ " veces" );
    }
}
```

Comment: Se tendría que cambiar la forma que repite el bucle, la idea debe ser que sólo salga del bucle cuando selecciona la opción 4 por algo es la opción de salir y no con las opciones (s/n)